# How to select an element by classname using jqLite?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite

I'm trying to remove jquery from my Angular.js app in order to make it lighter, and put Angular's jqLite instead. But the app makes heavy use of find('#id') and find ('.classname'), which are not supported by jqLite, only 'tag names' (as per documentation)

wondered what do u feel would be the best approach to change it. One approach I thought about is to create custom HTML tags. for example:
change
     `<span class="btn btn-large" id="add-to-bag">Add to bag</span>`

to

```
<a2b style="display:none;"><span class="btn btn-large" >Add to bag</span></a2b>
```

and

```
$element.find('#add-to-bag')
```

to

```
$element.find('a2b')
```

Any thoughts? other ideas?

thanks

Lior

Comment: ID's must be unique, therefore it makes no sense to find an element that is a child of another element by ID. Simply select the element by Id. If your Id's aren't unique, change your ID to a class. Also, you can use `DomElement.querySelector(".myclassname")` to select a single decendant element using a css selector, or all matching by adding All to it: `DomElement.querySelectorAll(".myclassname")` That of course doesn't work in IE<9.

Comment: If you define an `a2b` element, you must have defined a directive.  Can you do what needs to be done in the link function of the directive, and therefore avoid the need to call find() entirely?  Similarly with your classes -- can you define directives and put the functionality you need into the directives' link (or compile) functions?

Comment: @KevinB Angular's jqLite is said to support 'only tag names'

Comment: @MarkRajcok I didnt define a directive. it seems to work in IE and chrome. but even if I would define a directive, why would it help? I would still need to get hold of a DOM element.

Comment: How come find('span.btn') or similar doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Fabi `.find` in jqLite doesn't support the `.btn` portion of that string

Comment: oh im sorry I didnt catch the "only tag names" part

Comment: In the link function of a directive, the second argument, `element` is the DOM element (wrapped in jQuery or jqLite).

Comment: Maybe you've already read this, but I thought I should share anyways - http://jaketrent.com/post/angularjs-find-element-in-context/

Comment: @Fabi jqLite does not support class names 

see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

     `$element.find('span.btn');`
 []
     `$element.find('a2b');`
[
<a2b style=​"display:​none;​">​…​</a2b>​
]

Comment: parent.find('#id') is an uncommon but perfectly valid thing to want to do.  It provides element #id only when that element is a child of parent, excluding it otherwise.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Essentially, and as-noted by @kevin-b:

```
// find('#id')
angular.element(document.querySelector('#id'))

//find('.classname'), assumes you already have the starting elem to search from
angular.element(elem.querySelector('.classname'))
```

**Note:** If you're looking to do this from your controllers you may want to have a look at the "Using Controllers Correctly" section in the [developers guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) and refactor your presentation logic into appropriate directives (such as <a2b ...>).

Comment: Thanks! to add from Ricardo Bin answer (angular's mailing list), $document injectable could be used too: http://jsfiddle.net/ricardohbin/fTQcs/

Comment: Unfortunately, the referred URL is no longer valid (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller), and there doesn't seem to be any replacement in that section.

Comment: No.
angular.element(document.querySelector('#id')) is the alternative to:
$('#id'), not for: elementArray.find('#id')

Comment: Right - but as we have found as we build new parts of our application in angular we sometimes need to "duct tape" older parts onto it for a while until they can be updated or re-factored. In our case we needed to load some old jquery/ajax data without modifying the existing mess so we did the following- $http.get('/Task/GetTaskStatsByTaskId/' + taskId).success(function (data) {
                angular.element(document.querySelector('#userTasksContainer')).html(data);
            });

Comment: If elem is a jqlite object it would be `angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('.classname'));`

Comment: Can we select element using `ng-model`? Using Angular element.

Answer (score 3):

angualr uses the lighter version of jquery called as jqlite which means it doesnt have all the features of jQuery. here is a reference in angularjs docs about what you can use from jquery. 
[Angular Element docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

In your case you need to find a div with ID or class name. 
for class name you can use

```
var elems =$element.find('div') //returns all the div's in the $elements
    angular.forEach(elems,function(v,k)){
    if(angular.element(v).hasClass('class-name')){
     console.log(angular.element(v));
}}
```

or you can use much simpler way by query selector

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#id'))

angular.element(elem.querySelector('.classname'))
```

it is not as flexible as jQuery but what

Answer (score 1):

If `elem.find()` is not working for you, check that you are including JQuery script **before** angular script....

Comment: Although the OP specifically asked about jqLite, for those using jQuery and expecting find() to work with classes and ID's as well this answer may certainly help.

Comment: To clarify: "If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.". Quote from: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element . jqLite contains find().