# Find child element in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working in a directive and I am having problems using the parameter `element` to find its childs by class name.

```
.directive("ngScrollList", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {

            var scrollable = element.find('div.list-scrollable');

            ...
        }
      };
})
```

I can find it by the tag name but it fails to find it by class name as I can see in the console:

```
element.find('div')
[<div class=​"list-viewport">​…​</div>​,<div class=​"list-scrollable">​…​</div>​]
element.find('div.list-scrollable')
[]
```

Which would be the right way of doing such thing? I know I can add jQuery, but I was wondering if wouldn't that be an overkill....

Comment: Not sure if this [helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283697/angularjs-how-to-find-using-jqlite)?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

jQlite (angular's "jQuery" port) doesn't support lookup by classes.

One solution would be to include jQuery in your app.

Another is using `QuerySelector` or `QuerySelectorAll`:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
   console.log(element[0].querySelector('.list-scrollable'))
}
```

We use the first item in the `element` array, which is the HTML element. `element.eq(0)` would yield the same.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6be56/)

Comment: Don't forget about `.querySelectorAll()` (for multiple select)

Answer (score 31):

In your link function, do this:

```
// link function
function (scope, element, attrs) {
  var myEl = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.list-scrollable'));
}
```

Also, in your link function, don't name your `scope` variable using a `$`. That is an angular convention that is specific to built in angular services, and is not something that you want to use for your own variables.