# Angular directive test - Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I am using Jasmine Standalone to test my Angular directories,

SimpleDirective.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('SimpleDirectiveController', function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
      name: 'Igor',
      address: '123 Somewhere'
    };
});

app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,

        // Isolate scope:
        // separate the scope inside a directive from the scope outside, and then map the outer scope to a directive's inner scope. 
        scope: {
            customerInfo: '=info'
        },

        //templateUrl points to an external html template.
        templateUrl: 'fixture/hello.html'
    };
});
```

fixture/hello.html,

```
<div class="customer"><b>Hello</b> {{customerInfo.name}}</div>
```

SimpleDirectiveSpec.js,

```
describe("simpleDirective Test ", function(){

    // Boilerplate starts from here...
    var compile, scope, element;

    // Name of the module my directive is in.
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    // The external template file referenced by templateUrl.
    beforeEach(module('fixture/hello.html'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile,$rootScope) {

        compile = $compile;
        scope = $rootScope;

        element = angular.element('<div data-hello-world info="customer"></div>');
        compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));
    // ...Boilerplate ends here

    it('renders the customer template', function() {
        var customer = element.find('.customer');
        expect(customer.length).toBe(1);
    });

});
```

I get this error,

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   fixture/hello.html due to: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'fixture/hello.html' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
>   you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Any ideas What I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a module for your template and put your template html into templateCache.

It should look like this:

```
angular.module("fixture/hello.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("fixture/hello.html",
    "<div class=\"customer\"><b>Hello</b> {{customerInfo.name}}</div>");
}]);
```

If you are testing with Karma, there is an automation karma module for this purpose called [ng-html2js](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor).

Comment: Well, it should be loaded in your test browser. So, try putting it to SimpleDirectiveSpec.js for now. If it works, then you should checkout ng-html2js to automatically inject it to your test browser.

Comment: And if you are using Grunt, you can use this module: https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js

Comment: Thanks. I put it in SimpleDirectiveSpec.js, then it fails my test of `it('renders the customer template', function() {
        var customer = element.find('.customer');
        expect(customer.length).toBe(1);
    });`

Comment: Are you using jQuery in this project? If not, jqLite find method is limited to lookups by tag name. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283697/angularjs-how-to-find-using-jqlite

Comment: So glad I found this post. I have been struggling trying to load directives from templateUrl for like 6 hours. The ng-html2js preprocessors would not work for me. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using karma html pre-processor for html template https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor. Make sure that module generated have the path name that matches the module name you are declaring  `'fixture/hello.html'`.

You can verify the files by opening chrome developer console and check the `source` tab, the modules would be loaded as js file. Make sure that the name of the module generated match.

Comment: I'm not using Karma. I'm on Jasmine Standalone.