# AngularJS element.find changes my objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little problem with angularJS when it comes to finding elements.
It seems that my objects are changed when i use `element.find('type').attr('id' ,someid);`

Here some further information:

- I use the directive only in one position
- I use angularjs 1.3.10.

i prepared a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/fW4HsbqRhMWiw8hSLTVH?p=preview
which shows what i mean. It alerts the previous found element after it has found another. What happens is that the previously found element is the same as the now found element ( a little bit tricky to explain, see the comments in the code to see what exactly i mean).

My link function looks so:

```
function link(scope,element,attrs)
{
    var _gradientCanvas = element.find('canvas').attr('id' , 'chColorGradient');
    if(_gradientCanvas[0].id === 'chColorGradient')
    {
        var _gradientContext = _gradientCanvas[0].getContext('2d');
    }
    var _overlayCanvas = element.find('canvas').attr('id' , 'chColorGradientOverlay');
    if(_overlayCanvas[0].id === 'chColorGradientOverlay')
    {
        var _overlayContext = _overlayCanvas[0].getContext('2d');
        alert(_gradientCanvas[0].id); //alerts: chColorGradientOverlay , but it should alert chColorGradient

    }
    var _arcOverlay = element.find('canvas').attr('id' , 'chColorArcOverlay'); 
    if(_arcOverlay[0].id === 'chColorArcOverlay')
    {
        var _arcContext = _arcOverlay[0].getContext('2d');
        alert(_gradientCanvas[0].id);//alerts: chColorArcOverlay , but it should alert chColorGradient
        alert(_overlayCanvas[0].id);//alerts: chColorArcOverlay , but it should alert chColorGradientOverlay
    }
}
```

Here is the template

```
<canvas class="chColorPickerCanvas" id="chColorGradient" width="255px" height="255px">
</canvas>
<canvas class="chColorPickerCanvas" id="chColorGradientOverlay" width="255px" height="255px">
</canvas>
<canvas class="chColorPickerCanvas" id="chColorArcOverlay" width="255px" height="255px">
</canvas>
```

i am not quite sure why it does this. i tried to debug into it with netbeans but it seems really that it changes my `var _gradientCanvas` etc after i called element.find another time.
Is there a reason for this ?

Comment: your code finds _first_ `canvas` inside an element: `element.find('canvas')` and then `attr('id' , 'chColorGradient')` changes its `id` to `chColorGradient`: `element.find('canvas').attr('id' , 'chColorGradient');`. Second time your code again finds _first_ canvas and changes its id to `chColorGradientOverlay`: `var _overlayCanvas = element.find('canvas').attr('id' , 'chColorGradientOverlay');` and so on

Comment: oh, i thought it was used to filter. I now have to find a different approach. Thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what actually happens:

- `element.find('canvas')` returns all cavases inside `element`.
- `element.find('canvas').attr('id' ,someid)` *changes* `id` attribute of *first* returned canvas.
- so, `_gradientCanvas[0]`, `_overlayCanvas[0]` and `_arcOverlay[0]` all refers to the same element - *first* canvas inside `element`. And this explains described behaviour - `attr('id' , 'chColorGradient')` doesn't filters by id, but changes id of first element in collection.

If you want to filter by id, look into this post: [AngularJS: How to .find using jqLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283697/angularjs-how-to-find-using-jqlite/17329630#17329630)

Comment: since i know the order of elements in the template would it be considered save to use var canvasses = element.find('canvas'); var c1 = canvasses[0]; var c2 = canvasses[1]  to get the element i am wanting ?

Comment: yes, if you can confirm that order woudn't change, you can rely on it, here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3C9Pjn?p=preview)

Comment: okay thanks i will keep that in mind when changing my code. Since your answer explains where i was wrong, another helpfull thread is contained and seems to help me along i will mark his as accepted answer.