# getting angular element using nested classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

In my angularjs application on ng-click on a button, I have

```
$scope.getItems = function() {
    var matchedElements = angular.element(document).find('.main_tabSet');
    console.log(matchedElements.length);
}
```

which is working fine.

Now there are few bootstrap classes which are injected below `main_tabSet`, which I am trying to access in ng-click as

```
 var matchedElements = angular.element(document).find('.main_tabSet .nav .nav-tabs');
```

but this is not returning the elements. What is the right way of accessing elements using nested classes?

Comment: `find()` is only to look up by tag names anyway not classes // id\s.. Here is the docs with your answer too.. : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Worth noting that you can add full jquery into the page, in which case your selector should then work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How to .find using jqLite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283697/angularjs-how-to-find-using-jqlite)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `querySelector` like so :

```
var matchedElements = angular.element(document.querySelector('.main_tabSet .nav .nav-tabs'));
```

[Elemenet documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

From their own docs on `find()` : f

> find() - Limited to lookups by tag name

And very much related question :

> [AngularJS: How to .find using jqLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283697/angularjs-how-to-find-using-jqlite)