# jQuery Lite Element Finder with Ng-If on Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a directive with two html elements, one is an `ng-if` directive and the other is not:

```
  <div>
     <div ng-if="true" id="ngIfTest">TEST WITH NG-IF</div>
  </div>

  <div>
     <div id="withoutNgIfTest">TEST WITHOUT NG-IF</div>
  </div>
```

I select the elements like so:

```
var ngIfElement = angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('#ngIfTest'));
var noNgIfElement = angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('#withoutNgIfTest'));
```

I am able to select the element that does not use ng-if, but not the one that does.

[LIVE EXAMPLE HERE (Click on the text to see it selecting one properly)](http://jsfiddle.net/793k24td/)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope,elem) {
        
            //var myDivElement = elem #myDiv;
                var myDivElement = angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('.myDiv'));
        
                elem.bind('click', function() {
                    elem.css('background-color','red');
                    myDivElement.css('color','blue');
                    console.log('Element clicked');
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.color = "red";
                    });
                });
                
        }
    }
});


function MyCtrl($scope) {    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div id="me" style= "background-color:yellow;" my-directive>
          <div id="myDiv" class="myDiv">TEST</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I realize that this has to do with ng-if creating its own scope, but I am not sure how to get around it.

Related question that I am drawing from: [AngularJS: How to .find using jqLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283697/angularjs-how-to-find-using-jqlite?lq=1)

Comment: Note that your jsFiddle (and therefore the imported snippet) does not include the `ngIf` directive...

Comment: Looks like I didn't save changes. I will update later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really an issue of creating it's own scope, it's because `ngIf` doesn't write to the DOM when the condition isn't satisfied, so your jQuery selector never finds it. Use `ngShow` and `ngHide` if you need the element to exist in the DOM and be queryable.

Comment: Seems logical enough, upvoted. Will come back to accept in couple of days.