# Using $document.querySelectorAll in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As `$document` is wrapper for `angular.element(window.document)`, ideally 
`$document.querySelectorAll()` should work, but I am getting an error saying it is not a function. Can somebody explain?

Comment: jqLite object don't get values that wrapped object have to get querySelectorAll working you will need to use `$document[0].querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by using jqlite .find() method in angular.

```
$document.find('tagName.className')
```

Comment: This won't work with ".className" by design. You can find the corresponding note on [official angular.element api reference page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: its 'tagName.className', so it still search for tag, which the documentation also says. I have used this in my code and works fine

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `$document`, you should inject it (you can use any other way to inject it):

```
     angular.module('someModule', [])
         // instead of 'controller' use whatever it is...
         .controller ('SomeName', ['$document', function($document) { 
             // ...
         }]);
```

Then you can use query selector (notice the use of `[0]`):

```
$document[0].querySelectorAll(/* whatever */);
```

Comment: If the OP is interested in using `querySelectorAll`, or any method from the DOM API, then injecting the `$document` is unnecessary. It's a method on the globally available `document` object. This is just vanilla javascript. Injecting `$document` and then extracting `document` from it is an unnecessary step. I would suggest instead that the OP used a jQuery lite method if he or she is injecting the `$document`. Otherwise stick to plain old `document`.

Comment: good point. this is also an option. but jqLite `find()` is available only by tag name. in order to search by id or by class DOM API should be used.

Comment: What makes you think you can only query by tag name? [See docs on `find(..)`](https://api.jquery.com/find/). Any valid CSS selector should work.

Comment: you are looking at the wrong docs. on jqLite (which is not jQuery) only search by tag is available using `find()`, see the docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use...

```
document.querySelectorAll(..)
```

Omit the `$` because you don't need jQuery lite since you're just using the DOM API. Otherwise use a jQuery lite method... [this link seems pertinent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283697/angularjs-how-to-find-using-jqlite).

Comment: My intention was never to provide a cross-browser solution. It was to solve why `querySelectorAll` was `undefined` on the `$document` object. And fyi, [It works on many browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselectorall).

Comment: Best not to give this advice, because it's not a best practice in AngularJS. From the docs: "In AngularJS we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing."   The same goes for referring to `document`, as it may not be defined in mocked test environments. So that means it should be accessed either via `$window.document.querySelectorAll` or via `$document[0].querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `angular.element(document.querySelector().jqLiteMethods());`

For example

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#dis-caret-drop')).find('.caret').css({'opacity' : 0.4});
```

This would *select the element with id* **'dis-caret-drop'** and search for the *child element with class* **'caret'** and change the opacity of the child element to 0.4