# $document.find doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue with $document.find, I need to scroll to a form error on submit.

```
var errors = $document.find('.input-name:not(.ng-hide)');
```

This is called when a form is submitted but has errors. On click it finds nothing, however if I click again a second later it has found the errors and I can scroll to it successfully. I believe it has something to do with watchers and the digest loop, but I've been messing with it for too long and thought I'd ask. Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: sytax error: Should be $(document).find not $document.find

Comment: to find an element in angular... see this one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283697/angularjs-how-to-find-using-jqlite

Comment: That's worked perfectly. I had the same functionality working elsewhere, I had $document defined as a dependency, I must have got confiused, but that's great many thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this

and make sure to use $document in controller.

var errors = $(document).find('.input-name:not(.ng-hide)');